# Does pouch views duplicate the values they emit?

Tags: pouchdb

I have been using a view in pouchdb for some time and today I started to think about it.  I'm not sure if I'm doing things right or if I'm wasting space.

My application requests  documents in two ways: 
- A regular one wich queries for the full document, once at a time 
- A "list all query" that asks for skinny versions of all the documents

A skinny document is a document that includes all the fields except one (the text) that is usually the big boy of the document. If they were word documents a skinny version would include all the Metadata (author, modification date, title...)  but not the text.

For the second query I built a view that emits all the fields (with certain structure) except the big one (the text) , and then I just query that view. Is this approach correct or I'm wasting space because all the documents are stored twice except for the text field? In fact I'm not sure if that fields are being stored twice or just being indexed.

If this approach is not the correct one, which one could be better?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

## Prevailing rule of thumb

I think the prevailing rule of thumb is to emit as little as possible and rely on `include_docs`. Since there are so many stores each running on clients with different mixes of real and imposed resource limits, it is impossible to say what will perform best in the scenerios that become the most critical for you. But `include_docs` is the more conservative approach since the needed resources should stay more or less even with the database size rather fluctuating between more and less than the actual database in rather unpredictable ways.

## Reasoning

### Relevant Keys are an unavoidable cost

In terms of the structure/order of fields to make significant key ordering/grouping it is always going to be necessary to duplicate some fields to craft a [collatable key](https://github.com/pouchdb/collate) which can't share by reference with its inputs as it has a new structure.

### Emitting unnecessary Keys and Values is an avoidable cost

When repeating everything but the longest field to avoid the underlying document, I think that is close to a variant of this PouchDb Blog don't:

[2. Don't emit(doc.foo, doc)](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/9c25a2351c51507e75b5a785a1fcb2c6dad66c33/docs/_posts/2014-06-17-12-pro-tips-for-better-code-with-pouchdb.md#2-dont-emitdocfoo-doc)

### But partial documents might be beneficial in low RAM scenerios

On the plus side, since you are excluding the longest field, I think there is a possibility you are saving some RAM usage some of the time (a store+adapter setup in such a way that it avoids loading the documents in memory could have no reference to that JS String to share with the loaded doc so accessing the doc could need more memory than using the view's partial copy.)

### Yet that isn't predictable, and RAM is usually a secondary concern

But I wouldn't really count on that during all operations on all stores and that may be minimizing for the wrong problem (for many use cases where browser permanent storage limits, poor/expensive networking, and/or time building views during replication could be more noticeable.) Then there is also the problem that all of your other copied/seriailized fields are unlikely to share references with the copies of the doc when it is open. The metadata around small Strings can be more significant at runtime than their lengths.

## Alternatives

### linked documents

If I were going to try to separate out large fields, I think I would do so by using [linked documents](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#linked-documents) which then requires a view just to include everything from the current "single document" lookups, but would allow interesting ways to have filtered replication, etc for small/low bandwidth clients. In that configuration, I think alternate view designs could smooth the differences by emitting alternate references to stub documents, etc.

### But probably not Attachments

Attachments create a softer separation between the fields that still keeps them under the monitoring of the same revision field, (this is a flaw of relying on linked documents if some fields are only correct in the context of a specific update of another field.) While attachments may be left on disk more often on some stores, they could blow up to be Base64 on other stores and make the field a larger exception to work with. They also need to travel with the document which makes it hard to do anything interesting with the resting storage size of minimal replications, etc.

## PouchDb-find

[Pouchdb-find](http://nolanlawson.github.io/pouchdb-find/) makes the indexing only worry about relevant keys for everyone, like the recommended `include_docs` setup today, but then it allows you to request your specific fields which could save RAM depending on exact store+adapter implementation. Unfortunately, the API is not yet stabilized and implemented across Couchdb compatible databases.

Comment: pouchdb-find is just a wrapper around normal mapreduce. It will create design documents with normal mapreduce views and query them with `include_docs: true`.

Comment: @fiatjaf find allows those views to be shared if that storage is the tradeoff you want to make, and its user side API footprint allows include_docs to be removed without your knowledge in a future version.. So if it were stabalized it would be the best future proof option for getting good results. When you use include_docs yourself, then no layer can optimize that out for you once a better option is available.

Comment: I don't see how PouchDB will support any better way to store and index data than what it already does. Future optimizations to pouchdb-find will not provide optimizations not doable with custom mapreduce views today, unless PouchDB changes its entire data storage model (which would necessarily mean CouchDB uncompatibility, breaking API changes, data migration etc., i. e., another library).

Comment: @fiatjaf I don't have any problem with how pouchdb does indexes when only document references are emitted, that is your criticism not mine. Turning results from the reference to document fields without either wasting storage on copying the desired fields or RAM on loading large documents for subfields could be done better and the change hidden from clients iff clients aren't given the whole document whether they want it or not. Therefore find can improve itself in the way I care about, while other options require a client rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it right. The way you're doing is **simpler**, **faster**, **saves RAM** and makes proper use of CouchDB magical indexing features. It is also **flexibler**, since you can just change your view function later if you want and you get automatic index recalculation.

I'm against partitioning document data that belong together into more than one CouchDB document, as I explained in [this defense of "monolithic" documents](http://fiatjaf.on.flowi.es/the-monolithic-approach-to-couchdb-views/). In short: saving a lot of data in one document and emitting whatever you need from it is the only thing CouchDB indexes excel in, no other database can do it.

Of course there is the disk space problem, but I think that should be less of a concern than RAM, for example. Also, using CouchDB views, as powerful as they are, as just simple indexes, is kinda sad. As it should be clear now, however, this is just a matter of opinion (and it probably doesn't belong here on StackOverflow).

---

It goes without mentioning that you must examine your specific case and see what you want and expect, that no answer is the best for all cases and all that.